# Data Stack Exchange atom feeds for Stack Overflow

Tags: support, data-explorer

Can someone throw some light on the below url:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/atom

Where is it used on Stack Overflow and what is its primary purpose?

The above url will generate:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<service xml:base="https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/atom/" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:app="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2007/app">
  <workspace>
    <atom:title>Default</atom:title>
    <collection href="Badges">
      <atom:title>Badges</atom:title>
    </collection>
    <collection href="Comments">
      <atom:title>Comments</atom:title>
    </collection>
    <collection href="Posts">
      <atom:title>Posts</atom:title>
    </collection>
    <collection href="Tags">
      <atom:title>Tags</atom:title>
    </collection>
    <collection href="Users">
      <atom:title>Users</atom:title>
    </collection>
    <collection href="Votes">
      <atom:title>Votes</atom:title>
    </collection>
    <collection href="VoteTypes">
      <atom:title>VoteTypes</atom:title>
    </collection>
  </workspace>
</service>
```

Comment: So, an undocumented url produces an undocumented result?

Answer (score 2):

> Where is it used on Stack Overflow...

It's not.

> ...and what is its primary purpose?

It's an a feed showing the [OData](http://www.odata.org/) endpoints that Data Explorer exposes. For instance, [this request](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/atom/Votes()?$filter=PostId%20eq%20120955) produces Votes results for the [post with ID 20120955](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120876/c-superclass-constructor-calling-rules/120955#120955) on Stack Overflow.

OData support in Data Explorer is currently only lightly maintained, since using [the Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/) is almost always the better option.

Comment: Can I generate OData endpoints for my xml. e-g If I have some thing in xml format. how would I generate its oData say for something like http://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/152376, what would be its oData format be