# Hide the broken OData link in Data Explorer

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, data-explorer

The OData protocol was used in the past as a feature to get data from SE data dumps, but [is currently lightly maintained since the Stack Exchange API is usually better.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152651/data-stack-exchange-atom-feeds-for-stack-overflow/152653#152653)

The problem is that [it seems to be unavailable for more than 9 months](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230748/odata-feeds-are-down) and SE devs consider this as a low priority issue. [Quoting Nick Craver](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190017/odata-access-from-data-stackexchange-com-down/192382#192382):

> (...) if it breaks again due to another move or such we likely will
> not fix it. Supporting OData requires a lot of configuration and
> features in our environment that are otherwise not needed, it eats a
> lot of time (and somtimes resources) that are just really hard to
> justify given the usage it gets.

When you go to Stack Exchange Data Explorer and click in the [queries](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries) tab, you can see a small image-link about the OData feature. Clicking on it (https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/atom) shows a 404 error page.

In this case, I believe that best solution is to **hide this feature until it is fixed or SE decide to remove it**. Letting people to find this error is not a good UX approach. **Do you agree?**

Showing where the OData link appears:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Side note: I believe that this can be solved by us through a pull request in [GitHub](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer), but it's better to get community approval first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My [pull request](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/pull/63) was merged on Mar 27, 2015 and that was pushed, together with the recent changes needed for the Google Authentication, to production. Fixed and live in rev 2015.4.22.34